# How can i remove these? Expected method body?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, methods

What can I do to remove "Expected method body" and "Expected  selector for Objective-C method"?
 I can't remove them, and I have tried almost everything!

Comment: There is no description here of the what is causing this problem to occur, or what you have tried to fix it. Perhaps http://www.sscce.org/ will help us help you.

Comment: It is impossible to diagnose the error without seeing at least some of the code that causes it. It would also be helpful to have the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you (usually accidentally) add a stray character like `-` in your implementation file.

Check your recently modified `.m` files and make sure they're clean.